# Need help getting Scatter (IOC) services working

Tags: javascript, node.js, inversion-of-control, scatter-ioc

I've followed the sample provided on [Services](https://github.com/mariocasciaro/scatter/wiki/Guide#services) in great detail, but can't get mine to work. I cannot for the life of me see where I'm going wrong.

I'd expect output something like the following

```
Loading initializeApp
Loading Route 1
Loading Route 2
in initializeApp
Registering route 1
Registering route 2
App initialized
```

but instead get

```
Loading initializeApp
in initializeApp
App initialized
```

**Route1.js**

```
var self = module.exports = function(){
    console.log("Loading Route 1")
    return {
        register: function() {
            console.log("Registering route 1");
        }
    }
};

self.__module = {
    provides: ['routes/register']
};
```

**Route2.js** essentially a copy of Route1

```
var self = module.exports = function(){
    console.log("Loading Route 2")
    return {
        register: function() {
            console.log("Registering route 2");
        }
    }
};

self.__module = {
    provides: ['routes/register']
};
```

**initializeApp.js**

```
module.exports = function(registerRoutes) {
    var self = {
        initializeApp: function () {
            console.log("in initializeApp")
            return registerRoutes();
        }
    }
    return self;
};

module.exports.__module = {
    args: ['svc!routes/register'],
    provides: ['initializeApp']
}
```

**index.js**

```
var Scatter = require('scatter');
var scatter = new Scatter();

scatter.registerParticle([
    __dirname + '/lib'
]);

scatter.load('svc|sequence!initializeApp').then(function(initializeApp) {
    return initializeApp();
}).then(function() {
    console.log('App initialized');
});
```

I can get simple dependency injection working, but Services are killing me.
I've tried various tweaks, but can't get anything better than the output I've included.
The code included is the simplest I can make it, and closest to the sample provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you put your routes into a particle subdir? Your container is loading its particles from the `lib/` subdir. Are your routes in a particle dir? Something like `lib/<particle name>/route1.js`.

Comment: No, as there are no actual routes (just simulated routes), they're in the lib particle. Do the services need to be in their own particle?

Comment: Where does `initializeApp` go? in the `lib` particle, or the routes particle?

Comment: OK, moving the routes into a sub-particle under `lib` got everything working. Thanks Mario for the answer and the library :)

Comment: No problem at all. Give a shout if you need any more help.